# How can i get memory effective address of array in pintool?

Tags: intel-pin

I try to print memory location( effective address) of array, i found the following:

1- First way : by using ( for read operation as example) 
IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA 
 as argument to analysis function and print this value inside this function, (Effective address of a memory read, only valid if INS_IsMemoryRead is true and at IPOINT_BEFORE.)

2- Second way : by insert call backs:

INS_OperandMemoryDisplacement(INS ins,UINT32 n)
INS_OperandMemoryBaseReg(INS ins,UINT32 n)
INS_OperandMemoryIndexReg(INS ins,UINT32 n)
INS_OperandMemoryScale(INS ins,UINT32 n)
which returns displacement, base register, index register and scale values which used for addressing in memory operand, and calculate the effective address by the following equation:

Effective address = Displacement + BaseReg + IndexReg * Scale

What is the difference between them, and what is the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is somewhat complicated.

It's hard to know if you're indexing into an array as any memory location could be considered as an array with only 1 entry (and the instruction uses only a base reg).

Except by checking if there's a base, index, scale and displacement (I think we all can think of various contrived ways of indexing into an array without using SIB [scale, index, base] and displacement in one instruction), in which case we know **almost** certainly it is an array.

To keep the problem on reasonable grounds, let's say that all instructions that use SIB (or SIB + disp) are indexing into an array, and the other don't.

1. Your first way won't tell you if you have an instruction with SIB, it just tells you that you have a memory access [except if you then check if the instruction has SIB].

Moreover you need to check it's a read (IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA) or write (IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA) and you won't get fine details (like what is the base address of the array, what are the index and scale value, how much is the displacement).

2. The second way it the right one, I think. Not necessarily simpler but more exhaustive, from my POV (note that you can mix both methods).

Here's what I would do (code not tested, just a base idea ; works for both read and write accesses):

```
// we need at least one op
UINT32 op_count = INS_OperandCount(ins);
if(op_count == 0) {
    return;
}

// search for the operand which could be a memory operand
UINT32 current_op;
BOOL found_mem_op = FALSE;
for(current_op = 0; current_op < op_count; ++current_op) {
    // operand generates an address (LEA) or operand is directly a mem op
    if(INS_OperandIsAddressGenerator(ins, current_op) || INS_OperandIsMemory(ins, current_op)) {
        found_mem_op = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}

// check if we could find a memory operand
if(!found_mem_op) {
    return;
}

// get base, index, scale and displacement
REG reg_base = INS_OperandMemoryBaseReg(ins, current_op);
REG reg_index = INS_OperandMemoryIndexReg(ins, current_op);
UINT32 scale = INS_OperandMemoryScale(ins, current_op);
ADDRDELTA disp = INS_OperandMemoryDisplacement(ins, current_op);

// both base and index must be valid to proceed
if(REG_valid(reg_base) && REG_valid(reg_index)) {

    // get base register value
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)GetRegVal, 
            IARG_REG_VALUE,
            reg_base,
            IARG_END);

    ADDRINT reg_base_value = value_reg; //value_reg is obtained by GetRegVal() 

    // get index register value
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)GetRegVal, 
            IARG_REG_VALUE,
            reg_index,
            IARG_END);

    ADDRINT reg_index_value = value_reg;

    ADDRINT final_address = reg_base_value + (reg_index_value * scale) + disp;   
}
```

There's also an interesting example in PIN test suite in [source/tools/Tests/ea_verifier.cpp](https://github.com/jingpu/pintools/blob/master/source/tools/Tests/ea_verifier.cpp) (see IntrumentAccess function).